# How to get the azure VMUUID of azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-rest-api

I am creating an ARM template for the Azure Log Analytics workspace.it has some queries which use azure VM's VMUUID. Is there is any way to fetch the azure VM's VMUUID inside the ARM template or any other way to fetch azure VMUUID?
[ARM Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szWpa.png) I just need to get the values of VMUUID of all VM's in that subscription.

Answer (score 1):

## Try Azure Resource Explorer

You could easily find it in the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/).

//One more extra reference: [What is Azure Resource Explorer?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/)

Just navigate to the Microsoft.Compute => virtualMachines view:

[image]

There is one more way to find it, but for me seems more complicated as you need to connect to the VM:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/

### Update: Try PowerShell

The simple PowerShell script below returns a list of all VMUUIDs in the specified subscription:

```powershell
Get-AzSubscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "Olga's Subscription"
$GetVM = Get-AzVM
Foreach ($vm in $GetVM)
{
    $vmId =""
    $vmId = $vm.vmid
    $vmIdList +=$vmId + "`r`n"
}
Write-Output $vmIdList
```

Please let me know if above answers your question.

Comment: yeah It answers one of my question.but how to fetch the VMUUID of all the resources in subscriptions in ARM template dynamically?

Comment: What about the Rest API 'Virtual Machines - List All'
? Will it work for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall

Comment: Hey @SATHEESHKUMAR. I just wondering if you were able to review the "Virtual Machines - List All" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall or found any other way to fetch all VMUUID on a subscription dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this information programmatically from the Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS).  It provides information about currently running virtual machine instances. You can use IMDS to manage and configure your virtual machines. This information includes the SKU, storage, network configurations, and upcoming maintenance events. For a complete list of the data available, see the [Endpoint Categories Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows#endpoint-categories).

IMDS is a REST API that's available at a well-known, non-routable IP address `169.254.169.254`. You can only access it from within the VM. Communication between the VM and IMDS never leaves the host.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

Comment: Thanks for your response,I got the answer to one of my questions. but my question is about getting VMUUID values dynamically on the ARM template if I give the subscription id and name alone.